# How can I efficiently handle initialization and disposal of TextEditingController with Provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, texteditingcontroller

I'm encountering issues with accessing deactivated widget ancestors when disposing of the controller.

```
  import 'package:exposed/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:exposed/providers/commentprovider.dart';
import 'package:exposed/providers/userverifyprovider.dart';
import 'package:exposed/view/postScreen/comments/customtextcard.dart';
import 'package:exposed/helpers/styles.dart';
import 'package:exposed/services/firebaseServices/firebaseservice.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../../components/mybutton.dart';
import '../../../../components/mytextfield.dart';

class CommentsStream extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  const CommentsStream({super.key, required this.postId});

  @override
  State<CommentsStream> createState() => _CommentsStreamState();
}

class _CommentsStreamState extends State<CommentsStream> {
  late FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    Provider.of<CommentProvider>(context, listen: false).init();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    Provider.of<CommentProvider>(context, listen: false).disposed();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserIdProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Styles.heading(user.userId),
      ),
      backgroundColor: AppColors.bgColor,
      body: FocusScope(
        autofocus: true,
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          /* a streams of unique post comments. which takes a string parameter. 
          Inside getcomments: 'where' clause is used.*/
          stream: FirestoreService().getcomments(widget.postId),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              );
            }
            return snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty
                ? ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      /* A custom card for comments. has functionality to Focus
                      TextFeild*/
                      return Comments(
                          focusNode: _focusNode,
                          commentId: snapshot.data!.docs[index].id,
                          postId: widget.postId,
                          userName: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('userId'),
                          text: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('comment'),
                          avatarUrl:
                              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/07/12/17/post-976115_960_720.png');
                    },
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: Styles.whiteheading('Be the first to comment'),
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: Styles.getScreenheight(context) * .2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Consumer<CommentProvider>(
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                /*A custom text feild which takes multiple needed parameters.
                has a functionality to send comment and reply */
                return MyTextFeild(
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    prefixicon: value.txtbtnstring == 'reply' &&
                            value.commentcontroller.text.isNotEmpty
                        ? IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              /* String value for a button inside text feild 
                              because we wanted to switch it with reply*/
                              value.settxtbtnstring('comment');
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined))
                        : const Icon(Icons.comment),
                    controller: value.commentcontroller,
                    validator: 'validator',
                    suffixIcon: MyButton(
                        text: value.txtbtnstring == 'reply' &&
                                value.commentcontroller.text.isNotEmpty
                            ? 'reply'
                            : 'comment',
                        ontap: () {
                          /* postId can be accessed through 
                          snapshot.data.docs[index].id it is stored in commentidreturn
                          variable which is from our provider class name CommentProvider
                          */
                          value.txtbtnstring == 'reply' &&
                                  value.commentcontroller.text.isNotEmpty
                              ? FirestoreService().replyComment(
                                  widget.postId,
                                  value.personId,
                                  value.commentcontroller.text,
                                  value.commentidreturn)
                              : FirestoreService().addComment(widget.postId,
                                  value.personId, value.commentcontroller.text);
                          value.commentcontroller.clear();
                        }),
                    label: 'comment');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ProviderClass:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommentProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? _txtbtnstring;
  String? _commentidreturn;
  String? _personId;
  late TextEditingController _commentcontroller;

  String get txtbtnstring => _txtbtnstring ?? 'comment';
  String get commentidreturn => _commentidreturn ?? '';
  String get personId => _personId ?? '';
  TextEditingController get commentcontroller => _commentcontroller;

  void settxtbtnstring(String txtbtnstring) {
    _txtbtnstring = txtbtnstring;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setcommentidreturn(String commentidreturn) {
    _commentidreturn = commentidreturn;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setpersonid(String personId) {
    _personId = personId;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setcommentcontroller(TextEditingController commentcontroller) {
    _commentcontroller = commentcontroller;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void init() {
    _commentcontroller = TextEditingController();
  }

  void disposed() {
    _commentcontroller.dispose();
  }

  void setcontrollertext(String controllertext) {
    _commentcontroller.text = controllertext;
  }
}
```

Using Provider: I attempted to use Provider to manage the state of the TextEditingController and dispose of it properly when needed. However, I encountered difficulties accessing the TextEditingController instance from another widget where disposal is required.
I experimented with various combinations of initState(), dispose(), didChangeDependencies(), and other lifecycle methods to try to initialize and dispose of the TextEditingController at the appropriate times. However, I still encountered the error "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.